# How to avoid a JPQL query to execute to many SQL query?

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two objects Client and Procedure. A client can have a list of Procedure and a procedure can only be linked to one Client.

In the Client, I have a transient attribute nbProcedure, that exists to store the number of procedure fo a Client.

I use Spring data JPA, with the following Query :

```
@Query("SELECT new Client(c, count(p)) 
        FROM Procedure p 
        INNER JOIN p.client c 
        WHERE c.userId = ?1 
        GROUP by c.id")
fun getByUserIdOrderByNameWithNbProcedure(userId: String): List<Client>
```

I see in the log that this query is executed but after that there is one query executed per row to select all properties of the Client.

How can I avoid all the queries by row and only keep one query executed?

I think, I miss a configuration or a misuse of `new Client(c, count(p))`

Answer (score 0):

This can be because of not initialized lazy fetch associations in the entity. Can use `JOIN FETCH` instead of `JOIN` to avoid multiple queries.

Comment: I try but I get the following error : `QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list `

Comment: Are you using pagination in your query

Comment: I use the `PagingAndSortingRepository` in my repository